# How definition of isomorphism is defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

I have observed that isomorphism classes are sensitive to *abelianness* and *cyclic property*. Why mathematicians thought those as important to classify? Can anyone explain the motivations for choosing abelian property and cyclic property as important one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abelianness and cyclicity are considered important properties because they feature in a lot of theorems. Which definitions turn out to be the really important ones in a given mathematical field is not something which is *decided*.

It is not the case that one or more mathematicians meet up to discuss which properties of groups should be considered important. The process happens naturally and automatically as hundreds or thousands of mathematicians all study the field and publish their results: Suddenly one can look back at the entire theory and conclude that "abelian" and "cyclic" are properties which are used by many mathematicians in many theorems, and therefore they must be important.

Comment: @UnknownMathMan You need to keep in mind whether there is a bijective homomorphism between them. Apart from that, any property you can think of which seems relevant for one or both groups can be compared, and if you're lucky it proves or disproves isomorphism. But I don't think there is any known, definite list of group properties which always gives you a conclusive answer.

Comment: So in other word we have defined homomorphism after looking at lots of theorems? as isomorphism is defined using homomorphism

Comment: @UnknownMathMan How a definition appears in the first place is a different discussion from which definitions turn out to be important, and not one I know much about.